# How to call form Reset action on image?

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

I want to call Reset Action of form in my Reset Image. Can anybody give me solution how to call it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to handle that in PHP? Sounds more like a JavaScript thing to me.

Comment: Not concrete question. What you want? Reset form by click on image? Is it a simple image in tag <img>? Or it is a form element? It is a client-side actions. I don't know why you add `php` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a HTML and CSS task.

You can use this code here:

```
<input type="reset" value="" style="background: url(image_path); width:92px; height:31px; border:0px">
```

Answer (score 1):

if you cant use a reset-button, just add an onclick-event to you element (you image in this case) like this:

```
document.MyForm.reset();
```

for more information, take a look at [this](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/forms.htm#reset) (or simply ask mr. google)